# Pass by reference within template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I have a member function in my base class which takes argument by reference:

```
// Base
template<class Data, class Variable_Type = double>
class Parallel_Data
{
...
void FuncA(Data& data, int& Global_ID) 
{Data_Local.push_back(data); Local_To_Global_ID.push_back(Global_ID);};
}

// Derived
class Derived: public Parallel_Data<Atom_Placed>
```

The problem is when I try to call that function in the derived member functions

```
Push_Back_This_CPU(Atom_Placed(Position_Atom), Global_ID);
```

I get following error

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Atom_Placed’ to ‘Atom_Placed&’
```

I am just trying to pass the argument by reference and don't know why it wants to convert?

Comment: This has nothing to do with templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporaries like `Atom_Placed(Position_Atom)` cannot bind to non-const references such as the parameter `Atom_Place&`. The reason is that they are temporary objects and will die any moment now.

You could make a local variable of type `Atom_Placed` and pass that to the function `Push_Back_This_CPU`

```
Atom_Placed tmp(Position_Atom);
Push_Back_This_CPU(tmp, Global_ID);
```

Comment: I have a vector of objects of Atom_Place (not pointers to objects) which I'm inserting into it. If I create object separately, it will double the memory usage?

Comment: @Hesam if you already have these objects, why not pass those vector elements?

Comment: I meant, I am creating the objects (don't have them) but if I create tmp(Position_Atom) I need to free it every time (versus Push_Back_This_CPU(Atom_Placed(Position_Atom), Global_ID);) ?

Comment: @Hesam you need to look at your data structure: if you have a vector somewhere that is a member variable `v`, then that class needs to have a member function `push_back` that does `v.push_back( /* your data */);`

Answer (score 2):

You can't bind a temporary value to a non-const *lvalue* reference. However, since your function doesn't need to modify its arguments, the simplest solution is to take `const` references:

```
void FuncA(Data const & data, int const & Global_ID) 
//              ^^^^^             ^^^^^
```

Now you can pass temporary values to the function.

(NOTE: I'm assuming that `Data_Local` and `Local_To_Global_ID` have standard container interfaces. If their `push_back` functions also take non-const references, then they will need fixing too.)